# Call a stored procedure on an always encrypted SQL Server database

Tags: java, sql-server, always-encrypted

When calling any stored procedure from an Always Encrypted SQL Server database I get the following error:

> SQLServerException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0xC0 is unknown.

The table and the stored procedure was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table] (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [encrypted_col] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [MY_KEY], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_sp]
    @test_param nvarchar(255)
AS
    SELECT * from test_table where encrypted_col = @test_param
GO
```

The java code looks like this:

```
try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call test_sp(?)}")) {
    callableStatement.setNString(1, "TEST VALUE");
    ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery(); <-- Throws the Exception
}
```

My connection url looks like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;applicationName=MY-APP;databaseName=test_encryption;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;columnEncryptionSetting=enabled;enclaveAttestationUrl=http://localhost/Attestation;enclaveAttestationProtocol=HGS;
```

What causes this error?

Notes:

- I am using SQL Server 2019 and latest mssql driver (12.6), which are [compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16). I also tried downgrading the driver but results in the same error.
- Reading and writing data from/to the database tables works using Hibernate, which makes me think the connection url and encryption key are setup correctly. I only get this error on stored procedures
- The stored procedure can be called with success from SQL Server Management Studio, which makes me think the procedure and encryption was created correctly at the database level
- I have tried several other ways of calling the stored procedure, such as using Hibernate Query, or Spring Jpa Query, but they result in the same error.
- If I recreate the database table without using encryption, calling the store procedure works
- I have tried to use the database connection parameter sendStringParametersAsUnicode with both false and true values

Comment: Perhaps the problem is NString, you usually don't need to use that i think, does setString work?

Comment: Can you check the result of `select name, encryption_type_desc, encryption_algorithm_name from sys.parameters where object_id = object_id('YourProcedure')`

Comment: @siggemannen, NString is used for nvarchar parameters

Comment: @Charlieface the parameter has `encryption_type_desc=RANDOMIZED` and `encryption_algorithm_name=AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256`

Comment: I know :) But what happens if you do it through setString, do you have the same error

Comment: Isn't the first parameter of `setNString` supposed to be a parameter name, not an ordinal? Also what are your connection settings?

Comment: @siggemannen I have tried setString as well and updated the procedure to query a varchar encrypted column, but resulted in the same error

Comment: @Charlieface, the first parameter of setNString can be the parameter name or index. I've tried both. Also, I have updated the question to include connection string and table creation script